# Import list into SQL

Tags: sql, list, csv, import

I have an SQL database called 'Food' with a table called 'Fruit'.  Using phpMyAdmin I am trying to import a list of items from a text file which looks like....

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
Pear
Grape
Peach
Raisin
```

How can I do this or am I better off converting this list to a CSV and attempting it that way?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: What tool are you using for import, and what is the SQL platform you are using?

Comment: Sorry, I am using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to mysql command line then you could use the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/myfile.txt' INTO TABLE mytable;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html

Comment: Thanks, didn't know i could upload text files direct